# Sharing costs evenly

Tags: javascript, algorithm, math

The following problem: I have a number of people who want to share costs for something. For example a trip. Everybody pays a part and at the end it should be calculated who has to spend how much money to whom so that everybody is on zero. For this we have the following values

```
const total = 900;
const should = 150;
let persons = [
  {
    name: "mark",
    total: 100,
  },
  {
    name: "steve",
    total: 300,
  },
  {
    name: "bill",
    total: 130,
  },
  {
    name: "jeff",
    total: 70,
  },
  {
    name: "larry",
    total: 220,
  },
  {
    name: "jack",
    total: 80,
  },
];
```

I started by calculating the difference for each participant:

```
persons = persons.map((person) => {
  let difference = should - person.total;
  return { ...person, difference };
});
```

But after that I don't know what to do. The result should be something like this (pseudo):

```
Jeff to Steve: 80
Jack to Steve: 70
Mark to Larry: 20
Bill to Larry: 50
```

And this case is even simple. It can also be that one person has to give money to several other people. I don't know how to google for it either. Does anyone give me a hint on how to implement this? Or where I can find information that can help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a little ugly, but this will loop through all people who haven't paid enough, and will then find people who have overpaid and describe the "transfer" between them.

```js
const total = 900;
let persons = [
  { name: 'mark', total: 100 },
  { name: 'steve', total: 300 },
  { name: 'bill', total: 130 },
  { name: 'jeff', total: 70 },
  { name: 'larry', total: 220 },
  { name: 'jack', total: 80 }
];
const should = 150 // total / persons.length;
persons = persons.map(x => ({ ...x, diff: should - x.total }));
const ops = [];

persons.forEach(x => {
  // if person hasn't paid enough...
  while (x.diff > 0) {
    // find first person who overpaid...
    const payee = persons.find(y => y.diff < 0);
    // figure out how much needs to be paid...
    const payment = Math.min(x.diff, -payee.diff);
    x.diff -= payment; // subtract from payer
    payee.diff += payment; // add to payee
    ops.push(`${x.name} to ${payee.name}: ${payment}`);
  }
  return x;
});
console.log(ops.join('\n'));
```

Comment: That's Great! Thank You!